# Using multiple JButtons with the same label in Java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have two buttons in my project that both have a "+" label. When the actionPerformed() method is called, it calls a specific method based on the label. How can I distiguish between two JButtons with the same label? Is there a better way to do this then how I've done it?

This is  the definition of the buttons:

```
JButton keypadPlus1 = new JButton(" + ");
JButton keypadMinus1 = new JButton(" - ");
JButton keypadPlus2 = new JButton("+");
JButton keypadMinus2 = new JButton("-");
```

Adding the ActionListeners for the buttons:

```
keypadPlus1.addActionListener(backEnd);
keypadPlus2.addActionListener(backEnd);
keypadMinus1.addActionListener(backEnd);
keypadMinus2.addActionListener(backEnd);
```

The actionPerformed @Override in the backEnd:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("+")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }
        if (command.equals("-")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }
        if (command.equals(" + ")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }
        if (command.equals(" - ")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: `ActionEvent.getSource()` though it is likely they should have separate listeners..

Comment: Use separate listeners. Don't mix your responsibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this,

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("+")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }
        if (command.equals("-")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }
        if (command.equals(" + ")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }
        if (command.equals(" - ")) {
            calcLifePoints(command);
        }

    }
```

Use like this,

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
        Object command = event.getSource();
        if (command.equals(keypadPlus1)) {
            calcLifePoints(event.getActionCommand());
        }
        if (command.equals(keypadMinus1)) {
            calcLifePoints(event.getActionCommand());
        }
        if (command.equals(keypadPlus2)) {
            calcLifePoints(event.getActionCommand());
        }
        if (command.equals(keypadMinus2)) {
            calcLifePoints(event.getActionCommand());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

## You could...

Use `ActionEvent#getSource`

## You could...

Set the `actionCommand` property of each button to something unique and use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand`

## You could...

Use separate listeners, either anonymously or as inner or outer classes depending on your needs

## You could...

Make use of the `Action` API, which would allow you to define a common/abstract `Action` which defined the common properties (like the `+` text) and then extend this to make unique actions for each button

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

## You could...

Use `JButton#putClientProperty` to set some unique flag on each button and cast the `ActionEvent` to a `JComponent` and use `getClientProperty` to retrieve the flag ... but given the previous suggestions, I'm not sure why you'd bother

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have a single listener handle the behavior for different responsibilities. If the two `+` buttons do not do the same thing, **give the buttons separate listeners.**

This will allow your code to be a lot more cohesive. By reducing your listeners to 1 responsibility each, you'll be able to re-use those responsibilities. It also make testing easier, allowing you to test each behavior in complete isolation.

Although if you must, `ActionEvent#getSource()` returns which ever component triggered the event. Doing a *reference comparison* will allow you to determine which object triggered the event.

---

The best way to handle this would to separate the responsibilities your current listener has into separate classes:

```
class FirstListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Lets assume `FirstListener` represents your first `+` button behavior. If that behavior requires any external objects (such as a field in a different class), simply pass it through the constructor:

```
class FirstListener implements ActionListener {
    private Object dependency;

    public FirstListener(Object dependency) {
         this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    //actionPerformed declaration
}
```

You can do the same for the other buttons (for example, the second `+` button).

If you feel this is a bit excessive, feel free to use lambda expressions to declare the listeners:

```
//Java 8+
button.addActionListener(event -> {

});
```

This doesn't give you the same modularity as the previous example, as the behavior is no longer separated from the actual class: you will be forced to change the implementation to change the behavior, rather than using dependency inversion to simply pass a different object which also implements `ActionListener`.

Comment: How would I go about using two different listeners?

Comment: @VanSpoof Simply create a new listener. `ActionListener` is an *functional interface*, meaning you can actually define it via a lambda expression. Although if you want to stay modular, you could create a new class for each listener (which implements `ActionListener`), passing whatever dependencies are needed through the constructor.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @VanSpoof No problem :) I've edites my answer with an example