# Figuring out which button of array was clicked

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface

I got two-dimensional array of JButtons, I need to know which of them was clicked. Actually i need the coordinates *j* and *k*.
Code looks like this:

```
public void loop_button(){

        int size = jSlider1.getValue();
        getContentPane().remove(jSlider1);
        JButton[][] numButton = new JButton[size][size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){

         numButton[i][j] = new JButton("");
         getContentPane().add(numButton[i][j]);

        }

        }}
```

Is there any way to figure it out?

Comment: You can use `ActionEvent#getSource` but it'd probably be better to use `ActionEvent#getActionCommand`, you can also use `JComponent#put/getClientProperty` to store arbitrary values agains the button and extract it when the `ActionListener` is called

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880846/using-multiple-jbuttons-with-the-same-label-in-java/35880892#35880892)

Comment: `getActionCommand` returns blank string.I did it just like in this tutorial [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/ActionEventgetActionCommand.htm)

Comment: Use `JButton#setActionCommand` to change the `actionCommand`, this is defaulted to the text of the button unless otherwise specified

Comment: how can i access the button without clicking on it? e.g. in another method, i need to change background color of some buttons - but of course i need some ID  @MadProgrammer

Comment: You need to make the `JButton` array (I'm assuming) and instance field so it's available to your class